# Метод Рунге-Кутта и метод Милна(поиск шага интегрирования)

Tags: c++, математика, численные-методы

Мне нужно написать метод Рунге Кутта(4 порядка) и метод Милна для решения задачи Коши, сами методы несложные, а вот подбор шага интегрирования поставил меня в тупик, я так понял, что нужно найти решение задачи Коши в точке x0 + h0 и x0 + 2* h0, затем, путем увеличения или уменьшения в 2 раза шага h, нужно подобрать максимальное значение h0, при котором выполняется неравенство (1/15)* |y - y'| < eps, где eps задается с клавиатуры, y - Решение задачи Коши в точке x0 + h0, y` - решение задачи Коши в точке x0 + 2*h0. Я написал код для вычисления шага интегрирования, но просто не могу продвинуться дальше, как мне выполнять сравнение и все же, возвращать найденный максимальный шаг интегрирования?

Задание звучит так:

1. найти шаг интегрирования h для решения задачи Коши с точностью eps.

2.Решить на отрезке [a;b] задачу Коши методом Рунге-Кутта (4 порядка) и методом Милна с найденным шагом h.

```
double GetTheStep(double eps, double h0, double a, double b) {
double k1, k2, k3, k4, k11, k21, k31, k41;
double h = h0 * 2;
double x[22], y[22], y0[22], x0[22];
x[0] = a;
y[0] = 1.0;
x0[0] = a;
y0[0] = 1.0;
int i = 1;
do {
    k1 = h0 * f(x[i - 1], y[i - 1]);
    k2 = h0 * f(x[i - 1] + h0 / 2, y[i - 1] + k1 / 2);
    k3 = h0 * f(x[i - 1] + h0 / 2, y[i - 1] + k2 / 2);
    k4 = h0 * f(x[i - 1] + h0, y[i - 1] + k3);
    x[i] = x[i - 1] + h0;
    y[i] = y[i - 1] + (k1 + 2 * k2 + 2 * k3 + k4) / 6;
    //---------------------------------------------//
    k11 = h * f(x0[i - 1], y0[i - 1]);
    k21 = h * f(x0[i - 1] + h / 2, y0[i - 1] + k11 / 2);
    k31 = h * f(x0[i - 1] + h / 2, y0[i - 1] + k21 / 2);
    k41 = h * f(x0[i - 1] + h, y0[i - 1] + k31);
    x0[i] = x0[i - 1] + h;
    y0[i] = y0[i - 1] + (k11 + 2 * k21 + 2 * k31 + k41) / 6;
    h0 *= 2;
    h *= 2;
    ++i;
} while ((1. / 15.) * abs(y[i] - y0[i]) > eps);
return h0; 
}
```

Изначально, шаг h0 вычисляется как корень 4 степени из eps, которое вводится с клавиатуры

Comment: Не к вопросу, но... `static_cast<double>(1 / 15)` даст 0, потому что сначала вычисляется целочисленное деление `1/15`, а уже потом - приведение типа (ненужное...) Пишите просто - `1./15.`. И еще - никакого сравнения в условии `while` у вас нет. По делу - вообще-то считается с шагом h и с шагом h/2, а затем сравниваете значения y *для одной и той же точки* x, но вычисленные с разным шагом, а не в разных точках, как написали вы. Идти достаточно только в сторону уменьшения. Где именно проверять разницу - в одной конечной ли точке, или по всем просчитанным точкам - зависит от условия.

Comment: @Harry Спасибо, забыл добавить сравнение с eps

Comment: @TryHackChannel, вы ошиблись излагая метод подбора шага интегрирования. `|y - y'|` должен вычисляться для одной и той же точки `x`. А у вас получаются разные иксы для разных игреков.

Comment: @Harry Получается так, что я нахожу шаг интегрирования, минимизируя его(т.е. умножая на 0.5), а не будет ли так, что получится слишком большое количество итераций для данного шага? Может быть, нужно как то искать как в сторону уменьшения, так и в сторону увеличения?